# How to suppress webdriver-manager logs

Tags: webdrivermanager-java

I am using webdrivermanager to manage the drivers in my project but on updating to the latest version 2.2.1 my project is flooded with webdrivermanger logs, the logs are causing hassle while searching for my own stuff in the logs. How can I stop/suppress these logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is "solved" by adding logback.xml file to resources folder with following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="httpclient" level="ERROR" />
</configuration>
```