# How to suppress logging in WebDriverMangager for Python?

Tags: python, selenium, logging, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-python

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227305/how-to-suppress-webdriver-manager-logs), but that is for Java.

I wish to suppress the following:

```
INFO:WDM:====== WebDriver manager ======
INFO:WDM:Current google-chrome version is 88.0.4324
INFO:WDM:Get LATEST driver version for 88.0.4324
INFO:WDM:Driver [C:\Users\user.name\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\88.0.4324.96\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
```

Is there a Python solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python maintains concept to logging similar to Java. So you can alter logger's default settings with [ini file](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/logging/#example-configuration-via-an-ini-file) or [hardcoding](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/logging/#example-configuration-directly-in-code). You may choose new log error level [ERROR or WARNING](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels) - messages with INFO and below will not be stored then

Comment: Thanks, but the logging comes from WebDriver manager, I don't have access to its log settings.

Comment: @MateMrše Were you trying my suggestion? Logger is global for the whole application. So altered changes should apply all over thewhole application

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't been able to make it work. The problem is that the root logger has always been interfering with the custom one. Solved it with creating a separate logger.

Answer (score 4):

Seems it has been updated. New method to switch logs off:

```
import logging
import os

logging.getLogger('WDM').setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = "false"
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be fixed already in 3.5.0 version of webdriver-manager.

Try to set env variable `WDM_LOG_LEVEL=0`

P.S. please feel free to come on project's GitHub and describe your issue. There have been done much work on disabling default wdm logging, but if you still have a problem - give to author and contributors an example of code you use and they will try to help. https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, check to see if you have something similar in your code to this:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```