# webdrivermanager - turn off or reconfigure console logging

Tags: webdrivermanager-java

I am trying to change the console output produced by webdrivermanager-java from https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

I have found several tutorials on how to do that but none of them works for me (or I am missing something).

Here is the current console output:
[TestNG-PoolService-2] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Using chromedriver 91.0.4472.101 (resolved driver for Chrome 91)
[TestNG-PoolService-2] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as ...

I would like to remove it completely so here are the configurations I tested without success:

1. On another question here on StackOverflow: [How to suppress webdriver-manager logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227305/how-to-suppress-webdriver-manager-logs#)
   The solution is to add logback.xml to the resources folder - tested it and it does not work for me
2. On the github readme the author is mentioning how to influence logging so i have tested following config:

   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.hc").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);

but that does not work either.
I am using webdrivermanager version 4.4.3

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by adding logback to my project as a maven dependancy and a logback.xml file with logging config:

dependancy:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="httpclient" level="ERROR" />
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this in the official documents: https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/#troubleshooting

Setting the level of this to ERROR
`<logger name="io.github.bonigarcia" level="ERROR" />`
made those disappear from the console output.